# Joomla Version History Bug - UCM_History table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am getting the following error in my joomla 3.4.8 site all of a sudden. Only on articles though - can anyone help? If I clear the table data it enters the first row fine but then errors again (due to it trying to enter same ID as 0)

[image]

```
Error
   Save failed with the following error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `dxntv_ucm_history` (`ucm_item_id`,`ucm_type_id`,`version_note`,`save_date`,`editor_user_id`,`character_count`,`sha1_hash`,`version_data`) VALUES ('44','1','','2016-03-18 14:12:23','963','2464','029d533d644911092f599f0a8aa75b31c7f47548','{\"id\":44,\"asset_id\":\"207\",\"title\":\"Careers - Current Vacancies\",\"alias\":\"careers-current-vacancies\",\"introtext\":\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed after a DB backup and restore the auto increment disappeared from the table ID column - very strange!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable versioning flowing:

Content > Articles 
Top - Right corner click Options
Select tab Editing Layout 
Enable Versions to No

Comment: ALTER TABLE XXX_ucm_history MODIFY version_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2   (max of version_id +1 )

Comment: Similar ALTER TABLE `xxx_update_sites` MODIFY `update_site_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21